# Python's if key in dictionary not working correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a programming problem where user input can define variables, like so:

```
length = 1
```

When the user does this, I store the pair in a dictionary:

```
{'length': '1'}
```

The problem is, when I later try to check if a key exists in the dictionary, I always get False, even if it is definitely in there. Here is my code:

```
import math

def main():
    curr_formula = input()
    substitutions = dict()

    while(curr_formula != "0"):
        if("=" in curr_formula):
            split_formula = curr_formula.split("=")
            substitutions[split_formula[0]] = split_formula[1]

        curr_split = curr_formula.split(" ")
        for i in range(len(curr_split)):

            # this if statement never runs for some reason
            if(curr_split[i] in substitutions):
                curr_split[i] = substitutions[curr_split[i]]

        print(''.join(curr_split))

        curr_formula = input()
main()
```

The input "length = 1" and then "length + 2" should print "1 + 2" but instead cannot detect that the key already exists. Any insight on this issue would be much appreciated!

Comment: `while(input != "0"):` doesn't look right to me. `input` is a function object, so it will never be equal to the string "0".

Comment: @Kevin you're right, it was a typo. I fixed it in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Note: python doesn't require `( )` around conditional expressions, e.g. `while curr_formula != "0":` is perfectly legal and the canonical style.

Comment: @AChampion very true! Its a bad habit from switching between different languages often for various programming problem types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you split on `'='`, there is a space after the first term and before the second.

```
>>> 'length = 1'.split('=')
['length ', ' 1']
```

Whereas when you split on `' '` it's removed.

```
>>> 'length = 1'.split(' ')
['length', '=', '1']
```

As a result, the keys in your dict are probably different.

Comment: Ah, that fixed it. Thank you! I'll accept your answer once SO's minimum accept limit has passed.